# How to add/remove row (inputText ,ouputText) JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have this :

```
<p:outputLabel for="author" value="Author " rendered="#{documentController.show}"/>

<p:selectOneMenu id="author"
                 value="#{documentController.author}"
                 rendered="#{documentController.show}"
                 effect="fade"
                 editable="true"
                 filter="true"
                 filterMatchMode="startsWith">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{authorController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image]

I want to get behavior like this: If I click the add icon next to the author field then creates another 'outputText, SelectOneMenu , add link, remove link' for my second author,and if I click another one add icon then create third author and so on.

And the same thing for remove icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like this.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:panelGroup id="panel1">
        <ui:repeat value="#{documentController.author}" var="auth">

            <p:outputLabel for="author"
                           value="Author "
                           rendered="#{documentController.show}"/>

            <p:selectOneMenu id="author"
                             value="#{auth}"
                             rendered="#{documentController.show}"
                             effect="fade"
                             editable="true"
                             filter="true"
                             filterMatchMode="startsWith">

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{authorController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:commandLink value="Add">
                <f:ajax execute="@form"
                        render=":form1:panel1"
                        listener="#{documentController.addAuthor}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

On the backing bean you can do something like this.

```
List<String> author = new ArrayList<String>();
String s1 = "";
author.add (s1);

public void addAuthor(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajaxEvent) {
    String s = ""
    author.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but in the fact I want to save each author in a List of authors and then remove it if I want with a icon link ,Can you give me an example please!

Comment: Where you want the remove button?  Here in picture i can see only add button